# How to go through every file and directory on server and change group ownership?

Tags: linux, permissions, find, setfacl, chgrp

The goal is to loop through every file on the server, check if each file or dir has the 'groupA' group in the permissions. If the 'groupA' group is in the permissions, change it to 'groupB'. Otherwise leave it as is. I would really like to use the setfacl command but am coming up short. Got the closest with the code below.  Please help

`find / -group groupA -exec chown groupB '{}' '+'`

Comment: Do you actually have ACLs, or is this a simple "change the group of the file" request? If it's the latter replace `chown` (_change owner_) with `chgrp` (_change group_)

Comment: What about for the former?